# Using match function in VBA for coloring chart series

Tags: vba, excel

I have the following **dynamic** table,

[image]

The last column is a validation column that will mark the row for the MPs I am interested in,

This table will feed a graph in another sheet. What I am trying to do is:

**Identify the row in which the Identificators are added** (such as DT in this example), **and use this as the series number for the colors in a graph, in another sheet.**

What I am trying to do is

```
Dim DTrow As Long
Dim ORrow As Long
Dim EErow As Long
Dim OTrow As Long 


Set myRange = Worksheets("Financials").Range("M98:M103")
With Worksheets("NatCo Dashboard").ChartObjects("Chart 9")

    DTrow = Application.WorksheetFunction.Match("DT", myRange, 0)
    ORrow = Application.WorksheetFunction.Match("MP2", myRange, 0)
    EErow = Application.WorksheetFunction.Match("MP3", myRange, 0)
    OTrow = Application.WorksheetFunction.Match("MP4", myRange, 0)

    Select Case Sheets("Financials").Range(myRange)

        Case Is = "DT"
            Worksheets("NatCo Dashboard").ChartObjects("Chart 9").Chart.SeriesCollection(DTrow).Format.Fill.ForeColor.RGB = RGB(226, 0, 116)
        Case Is = "Orange"
            Worksheets("NatCo Dashboard").ChartObjects("Chart 9").Chart.SeriesCollection(ORrow).Format.Fill.ForeColor.RGB = RGB(255, 153, 0)
        Case Is = "EE"
            Worksheets("NatCo Dashboard").ChartObjects("Chart 9").Chart.SeriesCollection(EErow).Format.Fill.ForeColor.RGB = RGB(52, 161, 160)
        Case Is = "Other"
            Worksheets("NatCo Dashboard").ChartObjects("Chart 9").Chart.SeriesCollection(OTrow).Format.Fill.ForeColor.RGB = RGB(0, 0, 0)
    End Select
End With
```

I couldn't make it work like this, anyone knows what I could be doing wrong?

Thank you!

Comment: Don't leave the guessing work to us... "I couldn't make it work like this" doesn't help. Describe the problem.

Comment: @dv3, Im sorry I wasnt clear. The debugger steps into the code but I get an error: Application-defined of Object-defined error

Comment: in which line is the error? Also, you need to handle when something isn't found by match.

Comment: @QHarr, in one of the lines for the match functions, I think its crashing when it doesnt find the match, which will not be the same always

Comment: This needs some more explanation. You are testing a range with ("Financials").Range(myRange) to see if equal to a text value? Is it a merged range?

Comment: You should declare as Variant and use Application.Match

Comment: Dim DTrow As Variant  :  DTrow = Application.Match("DT", myRange, 0)

Comment: Will there only be one match out of the possible values?

Comment: @QHarr, yes, I expect at least one of the matches for every selection case

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If one is supposed to match and you are trying to change the colour of the line (and the lines are in plotted in the same order as in the range). You can revert to `.Format.Fill` if required.

```
Option Explicit

Sub test()

    Dim DTrow As Variant
    Dim ORrow As Variant
    Dim EErow As Variant
    Dim OTrow As Variant
    Dim myRange As Range

    Set myRange = Worksheets("Financials").Range("M98:M103")

    DTrow = Application.Match("DT", myRange, 0)
    ORrow = Application.Match("MP2", myRange, 0)
    EErow = Application.Match("MP3", myRange, 0)
    OTrow = Application.Match("MP4", myRange, 0)


    With Worksheets("NatCo Dashboard").ChartObjects("Chart 9").Chart

        Select Case True

        Case Not IsError(DTrow)
            .SeriesCollection(DTrow).Format.Line.ForeColor.RGB = RGB(226, 0, 116)
        Case Not IsError(ORrow)
            .SeriesCollection(ORrow).Format.Line.ForeColor.RGB = RGB(255, 153, 0)
        Case Not IsError(EErow)
            .SeriesCollection(EErow).Format.Line.ForeColor.RGB = RGB(52, 161, 160)
        Case Not IsError(OTrow)
            .SeriesCollection(OTrow).Format.Line.ForeColor.RGB = RGB(0, 0, 0)
        End Select

    End With

End Sub
```

**If instead you are trying to colour all matching lines  (which seems more likely):**

```
Sub test2()

    Dim DTrow As Variant
    Dim ORrow As Variant
    Dim EErow As Variant
    Dim OTrow As Variant
    Dim myRange As Range

    Set myRange = Worksheets("Financials").Range("M98:M103")

    DTrow = Application.Match("DT", myRange, 0)
    ORrow = Application.Match("MP2", myRange, 0)
    EErow = Application.Match("MP3", myRange, 0)
    OTrow = Application.Match("MP4", myRange, 0)

    With Worksheets("NatCo Dashboard").ChartObjects("Chart 9").Chart

    On Error Resume Next
        .SeriesCollection(DTrow).Format.Line.ForeColor.RGB = RGB(226, 0, 116)
        .SeriesCollection(ORrow).Format.Line.ForeColor.RGB = RGB(255, 153, 0)
        .SeriesCollection(EErow).Format.Line.ForeColor.RGB = RGB(52, 161, 160)
        .SeriesCollection(OTrow).Format.Line.ForeColor.RGB = RGB(0, 0, 0)
    On Error GoTo 0

    End With

End Sub
```

Edit:

If you want to set the colours for the others that don't match to some default then something like the following.

Note:

1. You can probably tidy this up
2. I have hardcoded the series for the `Else` e.g.  `.SeriesCollection(1)`
3. You would replace `RGB(1, 1, 1)` with your default for each line
4. If you know the index anyway then, for example, .SeriesCollection(DTrow) can just be  `.SeriesCollection(1)`

   ```
   Sub test3()

       Dim DTrow As Variant
       Dim ORrow As Variant
       Dim EErow As Variant
       Dim OTrow As Variant
       Dim myRange As Range

       Set myRange = Worksheets("Financials").Range("M98:M103")

       DTrow = Application.Match("DT", myRange, 0)
       ORrow = Application.Match("MP2", myRange, 0)
       EErow = Application.Match("MP3", myRange, 0)
       OTrow = Application.Match("MP4", myRange, 0)

       With Worksheets("NatCo Dashboard").ChartObjects("Chart 9").Chart

           If Not IsError(DTrow) Then
               .SeriesCollection(DTrow).Format.Line.ForeColor.RGB = RGB(226, 0, 116)
           Else
               .SeriesCollection(1).Format.Line.ForeColor.RGB = RGB(1, 1, 1)
           End If
           If Not IsError(ORrow) Then
               .SeriesCollection(ORrow).Format.Line.ForeColor.RGB = RGB(255, 153, 0)
           Else
               .SeriesCollection(2).Format.Line.ForeColor.RGB = RGB(1, 1, 1)
           End If
           If Not IsError(EErow) Then
               .SeriesCollection(EErow).Format.Line.ForeColor.RGB = RGB(52, 161, 160)
           Else
               .SeriesCollection(3).Format.Line.ForeColor.RGB = RGB(1, 1, 1)
           End If
           If Not IsError(OTrow) Then
               .SeriesCollection(OTrow).Format.Line.ForeColor.RGB = RGB(0, 0, 0)
           Else
               .SeriesCollection(4).Format.Line.ForeColor.RGB = RGB(1, 1, 1)
           End If

       End With

   End Sub
   ```

Comment: Thank you very much, it works at first point, however, when the data is refreshed, the new series turn into the correct colors and the series before remain the same color, so at some point I have the highlight colors in the entire series

Comment: You want to set default colours for the other lines and have only one highlighted?

Comment: One or more, based on the matches. So in this case I guess I should define default colors before changing it?

Comment: Yes. And you will want to have these set for the error values

Comment: It crashes on the `.SeriesCollection(4)` part, probably because I dont have the fourth series in this specific case. What I did is to define from 1 to 5 (series) and colors right above the colored ones (as you did in test 2), it works but it eventually crashes as well :(

Comment: Is there code I am not seeing where you plot the series? Are not all series present and you simply change the colour?

Comment: No, this is a dynamic table, that will be filtered based on this IN and OUT criteria, so the number of series is variable, I added 6 positions to the table because the current maximum is 6

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/168312/discussion-between-qharr-and-vferraz).

Comment: I replied to the chat

Comment: Noted. I have responded.

Answer (score 2):

Your `Select Case` is borked: It'll check the cell at the top of `myRange` (And, since `myRange` will already include the Workbook/Worsheet details, you don't need to use `Sheets("Financials").Range(myRange)`, just `myRange`)

At the very least, you need a `For Each <Range Variable> In myRange.Cells` to check each row individually.  But, if you're going to do *that*, you don't need the `Match` bit...

So, let's simplify: **You can just use the name to get the collection.**  (Assuming that you have given your series a proper/dynamic name)

Observe:  `DTName = Worksheets("Financials").Cells(6, WorksheetFunction.Match("DT",myRange,0)).Value` will give us the value from Column F (the 6<sup>th</sup> column), unless `"DT"` does not exist in `myRange`.  (But, that's what `On Error` is for)

```
Private Sub MuchShorter()
    Dim SearchFor() As Variant, SeriesName As String, SeriesColours() As Variant, lTMP As Long
    SearchFor = Array("DT", "MP2", "MP3", "MP4")
    SeriesColours = Array(RGB(226, 0, 116), RGB(255, 153, 0), RGB(52, 161, 160), RGB(0, 0, 0))

    On Error Resume Next 'Skip any series that don't exist
    For lTMP = lBound(SearchFor) To uBound(SearchFor) 'Auto-size
        SeriesName = ""
        SeriesName = Worksheets("Financials").Cells(6, WorksheetFunction.Match(SearchFor(lTMP), myRange, 0)).Value 'Look in Column M for the code, then get name from Column F
        If Len(SeriesName) > 0 Then
            ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("NatCo Dashboard").ChartObject("Chart 9").Chart.SeriesCollection(SeriesName).Format.Fill.ForeColor.RGB = SeriesColours(lTMP)
        End If
    Next lTMP
    On Error GoTo 0
End Sub
```

If you need any more tags, just add them to the `SearchFor` array, and add the colour to the `SeriesColours` array

Comment: Thank you very much, that looks very good! I have a little problem running this code,  on the line  `SearchFor = Array("DT", "Orange", "EE", "Other")` I get an error, error 13 - type mismatch

Comment: Ah - you may need to change the Array's from `String`/`Long` to both be `Variant` then

Comment: Now the code runs, but unfortunately the series color do not change accordingly